# Is it PCI compliant to create PaymentIntent directly from my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, pci-compliance, flutter-stripe

I have tried different ways to handle payment via no webhook flow, but the only solution is to call stripe API directly from my dart code as follows:

```
var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
        body: {
          'amount': _calculateAmount(amount),
          'currency': currency,
          'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
          'description': description,
          'receipt_email': email,
        },
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${AppConfig.instance.stripeSecretKey}',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
      );
```

is my code still PCI compliant and properly secured to use in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is still PCI compliant, but ***not secure***. Secret key must be stored securely in your web or mobile app’s server-side code (such as in an environment variable or credential management system). Calling from Dart means you are exposing your credential to the whole world. It's explained in [Stripe Doc](https://Must%20be%20secret%20and%20stored%20securely%20in%20your%20web%20or%20mobile%20app%E2%80%99s%20server-side%20code%20(such%20as%20in%20an%20environment%20variable%20or%20credential%20management%20system)%20to%20call%20Stripe%20APIs.)

Comment: Not to mention that if the amount to be charged is sent from the web browser, the customer can manipulate it to be $0.01, and you'll still get an "approved' response back.  Or they can just fake the response altogether.

Comment: to exclude this possibility, I am using official flutter_stripe PaymentSheet